Linear programming constraints for a line intersecting all line segments in set
I have a set of line segments that are defined as a connection between two arbitrary points (e.g. $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$). I need to find a line $y=mx+b$ that intersects all the line segments in the set at any one point. I understand linear programming is able to help with this, I am however not sure about the constraints. I believe that if the line segments are e.g. just vertical, a constraint like in this answer could work, but I am uncertain how this can be done if the line segments can have any direction.
I am new to linear programming so please excuse any mistakes in my question.
Thanks in advance

Are you sure that the form $y = mx + b$ is the one you want? If you had a bunch of horizontal segments, it might be that only a vertical line would pass through all of them, but such a line cannot be expressed using $y = mx + b$. Can you confirm that you explicitly don't care about this particular situation?

I hadn't thought about that, but let's assume for now that the line segments cannot all be horizontal to circumvent this. But out of curiosity, what form would you recommend if the line segments could all be horizontal?

I'd recommend either Ax + By + C = 0  or (angle, distance). In the second, "angle" is the angle of inclination of the line, between 0 and 180 degrees, and distance is the distance from the line to the origin (0,0). In the first, the case where $B$ is nonzero can be changed to $(A/B)x + y + (C/B) = 0$, which can be rewritten as $y = (-A/B)x + (-C/B)$, which has the form $y = mx + b$. When $B = 0$, we get an equation $Ax + C = 0$, which can be converted to $x = (-C/A)$, which is a vertical line. The case where $A = B = 0$ is not allowed.

The $Ax + By + C = 0$ is slightly annoying, however, because $2x + 3y + 7 = 0$ and $10x + 15y + 35 = 0$ denote the same line (as does any nonzero multiple of this equation). So when you try to find a line in this form, you typically end up with a whole "family" of $(A,B,C)$ triples, all of which denote the same line.

Parametrize each line segment $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ as
\begin{align}
x_k &= x_1^k (1-t_k) + x_2^k t_k \\
y_k &= y_1^k (1-t_k) + y_2^k t_k
\end{align}
where $(x_1^k,y_1^k)$ and $(x_2^k,y_2^k)$ are the endpoints and $0 \le t_k \le 1$.
Now the problem is to find $m,b,t_1,\dots,t_n$ such that $y_k=mx_k+b$ for all $k$.  That is, minimize $0$ subject to
\begin{align}
y_1^k (1-t_k) + y_2^k t_k &= m (x_1^k (1-t_k) + x_2^k t_k) + b \tag1\label1 \\
0 \le t_k &\le 1 \tag2\label2
\end{align}
But \eqref{1} is quadratic (not linear) in the decision variables because of the products $m\cdot t_k$.  When $x_1^k=x_2^k$ as in the linked question, \eqref{1} becomes linear because the RHS reduces to $m x_1^k + b$.
